# WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /in/recipeitems-latest.json._COPYING_

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I'm getting an issue when i try to copy the `json` from local path to Hadoop File Distributed System. I have followed the steps for coding that are given here in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform

I'm using Windows 8 OS. Please find the error below and help me to fix this issue.

In the cmd i have executed this command:

`D:\BigData\hadoop-2.7.1\sbin>hadoop fs -copyFromLocal c:\Hwork\recipeitems-latest.json /in`

```
> 16/10/04 20:20:53 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /in/recipeitems-latest.json._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
> 
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
> copyFromLocal: File /in/recipeitems-latest.json._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>
```

Comment: This is probably important: `could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s) running.`

Comment: I could not get what are saying but I have fixed the issue by reinstalling the hadoop. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below URL. Increase the "hdfs_user_nofile_limit" parameter in HDFS, YARN and MR.

[enter link description here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Increase-open-file-limit-of-the-user-to-scale-for-large-data/td-p/206502)